# Create List Item in Another Site Collection Using REST API from Visual Studio Workflow

Tags: workflow, rest, list-item, visual-studio-2013, cross-site

I have developed a List Workflow in Visual Studio 2013.

In this, I am trying to read the current item's `Title` and create an item in another list in another site collection.

Please read the last part clearly. I have to create an item in a list in a **different site collection**. But, both the site collections have the same user with contribute permissions. Since I have to create a list item in another site collection, I have no option than to use REST API to create a list Item. But to create a list item using REST API, I need to post a request to `http://{siteName}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listTitle')/items` URL and post the `type`, `Title` and other columns and `X-RequestDisgest` attributes in the payload. I am not sure, how to get the X-RequestDigest in my workflow.

If I skip this digest, I get an unauthorized exception upon checking it in Fiddler. Can anyone please help?

Comment: sitename/_api/contextinfo as POST will return the FormDigestValue in Fiddler

Comment: Thank you very much, Mick. But even when I put this Digest into the Authorization Bearer, it is not letting me create in another site collection. I am not sure, whether this is feasible or not.

Answer (score 0):

As MickB suggested, sending an empty POST request to `/_api/contextinfo` will return the FormDigestValue. You need to send this request to the site collection/list that you intend to modify.

Now POST an API call to the endpoint you've posted in your question. Use the returned FormDigestValue in the header for the "X-RequestDigest" (note the typo in your question).

Note that both requests need to utilize HTTP and not HTTPS.

Here is a good write up detailing the above in Fiddler:

[SP REST API with Fiddler](http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2013/09/03/more-on-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-with-fiddler-and-spd/)